# How can I use std::sort with objects that have no copy constructor?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, move-semantics

I'm trying to sort a vector containing objects that are not copy constructible or default constructible (but are move constructible), but I get errors about the compiler not being able to find a valid function for `swap`. I thought that having a move constructor would be enough. What am I missing here?

```
class MyType {
public:
    MyType(bool a) {}
    MyType(const MyType& that) = delete;
    MyType(MyType&& that) = default;
};

int main(void) {
    vector<MyType> v;
    v.emplace_back(true);
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](MyType const& l, MyType const& r) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to explicitly define a [move assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment), as this is what [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) also tries (not just move construction). Note that the compiler-generation of a move assignment operator [is prohibited](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment#Implicitly-declared_move_assignment_operator) by the existence of a user-provided copy constructor, as well as by the existence of a user-provided move constructor (even if they are `delete`-ed). Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class MyType {
public:
    MyType(bool a) {}
    MyType(const MyType& that) = delete;
    MyType(MyType&& that) = default;
    MyType& operator=(MyType&&) = default; // need this, adapt to your own need
};

int main(void) {
    std::vector<MyType> v;
    v.emplace_back(true);
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), [](MyType const& l, MyType const& r) {
        return true;
    });
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2729548fd3cb7a89)

The [slides](http://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014) by [Howard Hinnant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/howard-hinnant) (the main contributor to move semantics in C++11) are super useful, as well as *Item 17: Understand special member function generation* from [Effective Modern C++](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920033707.do) by Scott Meyers.

Comment: According to cppreference, `std::sort` requires the type to be move constructible *and* move assignable.

Comment: Spot on. The elements can't be move constructed because they all already exist; they must be move _assigned_ to swap their values around.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks, I am not absolutely sure why though `std::sort` *needs* to have its elements move-constructible also. My guess is that it uses a temporary (perhaps via `std::swap`) which is move-constructed.

Comment: @vsoftco: Yes I imagine that is so

Comment: Or, more accurately, that the specification permits an implementation of `std::sort()` to use a temporary.  Permitting use of a temporary (by requiring move construction) is not the same as requiring it.